# How to calculate the maximum number of turns possible on a ferrite core?

Tags: inductor, magnetics

I am designing a coupled inductor for a boost converter by following the step-by-step procedure for inductor design in Chapter 14 of the Fundamentals of Power Electronics. My specs are the following:

- Core Type: PQ 40/40, datasheet: https://www.ferroxcube.com/upload/media/product/file/Pr_ds/PQ40_40.pdf
- Material: 3C95
- Number of turns on the primary: 71 (#18 AWG)
- Number of turns on the secondary: 142 (#23 AWG)

I want to calculate the maximum number of turns possible on the primary and secondary given the wire gauge to ensure that this will be achievable. The bare area for #18 AWG and #23 AWG are 8.2x10^-3 cm^2 and 2.5x10^-3 cm^2, respectively.

Comment: Huh, why is there a secondary on a "boost"? What voltage, frequency and power level is this for?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm using a tapped-coupled inductor to achieve a higher voltage gain; the inductor here will essentially act as a transformer. The switching frequency is 300kHz and it will be 96W.

Comment: Someone came and downvoted the question and all the answers LoL

Comment: Ferroxcube data books prior to 1990 have graphs showing number of turns versus wire diameter.

Comment: On a PQ40/40 you'll need about a half dozen turns to get 300kHz and 96W.  It's a big core; I've make 1kW converters with these before. You may want to ask another question regarding size selection, before committing to wind all that wire.  Also consider stranding (litz is likely preferred/required at 300kHz) and interleaving (how the two sections should be wound together).

Comment: How did you calculate the wire diameter? AC loss (Proximity effect) + DC loss says that the optimum wire diameter (minimum loss) at 300 kHz for 71 turns is AWG #28; for 142 turns is AWG #30 on a PQ40/40 core.

Comment: @RohatKılıç - We are aware of that vote abuse and, with the kind assistance of Stack Exchange staff, it has now been handled and reversed. If you see something that's clearly strange like that, please feel free to raise a flag on any affected question or answer and explain what's happening in the "in need of moderator attention" text box. Even if we can't fix it immediately, the flag will alert us to something strange happening. Thanks! (I'll try to remember to delete the comments on this eventually, but I wanted to reply and let you know that we handled it.)

Comment: @qrk the wire diameter is given in Appendix D of the Fundamentals of Power Electronics textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bobbin or ferrite core datasheets provide window area, area of which the windings will be fitted in.

For example, you can find this information from [PQ40/40 datasheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/pq_40_40.pdf):

[image]

This is the maximum available area after fitting the core halves. Obviously, the entire area can't be used for windings only, but the number is still quite useful. Also you shouldn't use the total area because it affects thermal performance. Personally, I take up to 90% of this area for well-cooled systems, and up to 60% for convection-cooled ones.

---

Now for the maximum number of turns to fill the area, we can use geometry:

[image]

**NOTE:** The following calculation is for a single winding using #18 AWG **round wire** but I'm sure you can extend it to multiple windings and copper foils (rectangular cross sectional shape of a foil makes the calculations easier).

**W** is the window width (breadth) that we can get from the datasheet. For PQ4040 it's 25.4mm. Note that #18 AWG has a diameter of 1.02 mm but since it'll be enamelled the diameter will be **R = 1.1 mm**. So, the maximum number of turns to fit the window breadth will be

$$
N_L=\frac{W}{R}=\frac{25.4}{1.1}=23
$$

As can be seen from the image above, the second layer can't take 23 turns because of wire geometry. So it's going to take 22 turns.

The window height, **H**, can be calculated from the total area: \$A_N=W \cdot H\Rightarrow H=309/25.4=12.1mm\$. As can be seen from the image above, 2 layers take **~1.87 R** of window height. So the maximum number of layers we can put, **n<sub>L</sub>**, is

$$
n_L=\frac{2 \cdot H}{1.87 \ R}=\frac{2 \cdot 12.1}{1.87 \cdot 1.1}=11.77 \Rightarrow n_L= 11
$$

As you might have noticed, I made the calculation with an assumption of that the 3rd, 5th, 7th, ... layers start from the top of the previous layer. So you expect to see more layers. I made this intentionally, because I never want to fill the window area completely. This also allows me to leave some space for tape.

Now the total number of turns can be calculated: From the image above, 2 layers take 2N<sub>L</sub>-1 turns, therefore total number of turns will be

$$
N_{max}=\frac{n_L}{2} \ (2N_L - 1)=\frac{11}{2} \ (2\cdot 23 - 1)=247
$$

Or, putting all together:

$$
N_{max}\approx 0.95 \ \frac{A_N}{R^2}
$$

Again, this is for a single winding, but can be extended for multiple windings by keeping the turns ratio and safety requirements into account.

Some practical considerations:

- Consider the tape to be put between layers or windings.
- Consider the tape to be put on the side walls, if needed.
- Consider the insulation between multiple windings i.e. TIW (triple insulated wires) have larger diameter that occupies much larger area.
- Consider the safety requirements e.g. you may want to keep extra distance between the enamelled wires and core, or you may want to increase the distance between primary and secondary, by putting extra layers of tape.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what 'copper fraction' your winding technique will achieve. This is the amount of real copper in the winding window. This will be much higher for machine winding from a manufacturer, than an amateur's hand winding, who normally manages nice layers for a layer or two, before resorting to 'scramble-wound'.

As a rule of thumb, 50% would be a great achievement, but amateurs would be best to assume something like 33%. There's a lot of air in a scramble-wound winding! Some of that space inefficiency is unavoidable, so the hexagonal stacking, any inter-layer insulation, wire insulation, but some will be due to technique, crossing wires being the big space waster.

Take the area available to be wound, reduce it by the copper fraction, divide by the area of the wire, and you'll get roughly the number of turns you can expect. That's reasonable for thin wire. If you have thick wire and only a few turns per layer, then it's worth counting the whole turns you can get per layer, and multiplying by the number of layers.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to analysing the available mechanical area within the core after the bobbin is placed. This is from your [data sheet](https://www.ferroxcube.com/upload/media/product/file/Pr_ds/PQ40_40.pdf): -

[image]

All the dimensions are there in the data sheet and you know what diameter wires you want to use so do some calculations. If you don't know the wire diameters use [this table](https://metersuk.co.uk/american-wire-gauge-awg-cable-conductor-sizes/): -

[image]

And assume a 5% thicker wire for wire enamel insulation and a little bit of fudge factor.

One final thing: I didn't see any voltages mentioned in your question so, you need to ensure that stacked layers have sufficient insulation between them by using (for instance) polyester (or better) tapes. Image from [Transformer Tape](https://www.lodestonepacific.com/transformer-tape/): -

[image]